# Why does the Keras (Tensorflow 2.0) model does not include the variables of matrix multiplication, when plotted?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using the following code to build a deep learning model in Keras (Tensorflow 2.0).

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras = tf.keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

a = Input(shape=(138,7), name='inputP')
b = Input(shape=(138,7), name='inputQ')
c = tf.transpose(b, [0,2,1])
d = tf.matmul(c,a)
e = Dense(15,activation = 'relu')(d)
model = Model([a,b],e)
keras.utils.plot_model(model)
```

Following output is generated:

[image]

Here, the inputP is not included in the plotted graph. What could be the reason for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `plot_model` works properly, replace all those tensorflow operations like `tf.transpose` and `tf.matmul` with lambda layers such that every node in the functional API is a keras layer, i.e.,

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.keras.Input((138,7), name='inputP')
b = tf.keras.Input((138,7), name='inputQ')
c = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.transpose(x, [0,2,1]),name='transpose')(b)
d = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.matmul(x[0],x[1]),name='matmul')([c,a])
e = tf.keras.layers.Dense(15,activation = 'relu')(d)
model = tf.keras.Model([a,b],e)
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model)
```

Comment: This seems to work for general cases. But when I use MultiHeadAttention layer of keras, it does not work.

Comment: The code can be found here: 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fti2NZyAvbecM191UuT76xWGwHiz3RTT?usp=sharing#scrollTo=pnj5gj4gcrce

Comment: It seems that tensorflow doesn't support this for MHA. The workaround is to create a custom keras layer that contains a MHA and calls it. codes: https://pastebin.com/qmmURT3P

Comment: In general, if the graph does not match the written code, does this create problem? The training still happens smoothly (without errors) and number of trainable parameters do not change as well. The metrics also seemed similar in both the cases, when the graph was connected and when it had hanging nodes.

Comment: What you have mentioned so far should be a problem in the `plot_model` function and the computations should be correct. But in general, please encapsulate tensorflow operations(`tf.transpose`, `tf.matmul`, etc...) inside keras layer to avoid strange things happen.